# Synchronize critical section in API for each user in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, synchronization, critical-section

I wanted to swap a profile picture of a user. For this, I have to check the database to see if a picture has already been saved, if so, it should be deleted. Then the new one should be saved and entered into the database.

Here is a **simplified (pseudo) code** of that:

```js
async function changePic(user, file) {
  // remove old pic
  if (await database.hasPic(user)) {
    let oldPath = await database.getPicOfUser(user);
    filesystem.remove(oldPath);
  }
  // save new pic
  let path = "some/new/generated/path.png";
  file = await Image.modify(file);
  await Promise.all([
   filesystem.save(path, file),
   database.saveThatUserHasNewPic(user, path)
  ]);
  return "I'm done!";
}
```

I ran into **the following problem** with it:
If the user calls the API twice in a short time, serious errors occur. The database queries and the functions in between  are asynchronous, causing that the changes of the first API call weren't applied when the second API checks for a profile pic to delete. So I'm left with a  `filesystem.remove` request for an already unexisting file and an unremoved image in the filesystem.

I would like to **safely handle that situation by synchronizing this critical section of code.** I don't want to reject requests only because the server hasn't finished the previous one and I also want to synchronize it for each user, so users aren't bothered by the actions of other users.

Is there a clean way to achieve this in JavaScript? Some sort of [monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)) like you know it from Java would be nice.

Comment: You are checking if the file exists in the database, but not on the file system as well. If you make the additional check to make sure the file exists on the file system before you `remove()` it, that should stop the fatal error from happening.

Comment: @SundayCode I already do that. The main problem is the fact that this is even necessary and the file in the file system without a pointer in the database. I also block the user from spamming the API on the client side. But that is not the bulletproof way, because the user can still request the API from different devices or tabs.

Comment: Do you do that in the code you provided? Maybe I'm mistaken, I only see `filesystem.remove(oldPath))`. Is that a custom method that checks the path before removing? The only other thing I can think of is doing an atomic transaction in the database ORM such that the image record from the database is only deleted once the image is deleted from the file system.

Comment: @SundayCode I'm sorry. As I said, I simplified the code. I didn't want the part "So I'm left with a filesystem.remove request for an already unexisting file..." to sound like it is throwing an error I can't handle. With "serious errors" I meant the unreliable check with `database.hasPic` (which itself is also a simplification of about 20 lines of code) and the hole concept of the code snippet

Comment: Use database transactions, and handle the error you get from removing a non-existing file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a library like [`p-limit`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-limit) to control your concurrency. Use a map to track the active/pending requests for each user. Use their ID (which I assume exists) as the key and the limit instance as the value:

```
const pLimit = require('p-limit');

const limits = new Map();

function changePic(user, file) {
  async function impl(user, file) {
    // your implementation from above
  }

  const { id } = user // or similar to distinguish them

  if (!limits.has(id)) {
    limits.set(id, pLimit(1)); // only one active request per user
  }

  const limit = limits.get(id);
  return limit(impl, user, file); // schedule impl for execution
}

// TODO clean up limits to prevent memory leak?
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. With 28M downloads per week on npm it's a shame that I missed it when I was looking for a solution myself. Thank you.